# MVC 3 - Posting partial view to a chosen controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, partial-views

I'm trying to learn MVC 3 and Razor coming from a ASP.NET background.

I've want to get a simple partial view (in the shared folder) to post to a specific controller so that I can re-use it elsewhere such as for articles, blogs etc. I tried using variations of the following.

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Comment", FormMethod.Post,  new { }))
{
    <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Comments</legend>

            <div >
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)              
            </div>

            <div >
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)              
            </div>

            <div >
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Body)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Body)              
            </div>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
}
```

This doesn't post to the comments controller action Create as shown below.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create()
{
    // Save comment code here

    return View();
}
```

There is any simple way of doing this without having to bound to a specfic route?

Comment: What does the HTML source look like for the form that gets generated? What does happen when you click the submit button?

Comment: @mcl thanks for the comment. When I click on the submit button the URL changes to /Comment/Create and  I get an error Server Error in '/MVC3PartialView' Application. I want the URL to stay the same and post back to the comment controller. Do you know of any way to do this? Would maybe ajax solve this?

Comment: I think what you want is not quite possible without ajax, since pure HTTP thinks you want to POST the form to /Comment/Create. My guess is your partial above is called "Create"? Which means it won't work as a View for an action as well, most likely. Your create view needs to be something simple (but a complete page), like "Thanks for the comments" (and using a hidden form input you can get this view to provide a link back to the article).

Comment: Yeah your right I think ajax is the way to go. I nearly got it working turns out to have been a routing issue. I have map route (for CMS)            routes.MapRoute(
                null,
                "{*slug}",
                new { controller = "Page", action = "Index", slug = UrlParameter.Optional });                                                                 Always routes back to the same controller. I need to find a route that can work for the CMS as well as post forms in partials probably another question... Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer.

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm("Create", "Comment",  new AjaxOptions() {
        UpdateTargetId = "MainContainer"    })) 
{ 
     <div>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Comments</legend>

            <div >
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Name)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)              
            </div>

            <div >
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Email)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Email)              
            </div>

            <div >
                @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Body)
                @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Body)              
            </div>

            <p>
                <input type="submit" value="Create" />
            </p>
        </fieldset>
    </div>
}
```

This posts back using ajax and doesn't change the URL. Or you can do it this way using JQuery http://jvance.com/blog/2010/02/20/MakingAnAjaxFormWithJQueryInASPdotNETMVC.xhtml